# Vpn connection in c# on a server linux

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, connection, vpn

I have a database in a server and the only way to connect is through a global protect vpn but i don't know how to do that connection in c# for linux.

The problem is i can't change the connection of the whole server I have to do that connection only for the application.

I'm expecting to get the database connection in asp.net in a linux service throught the global protection connection.

Comment: What type of database?  You just need to modify the connection string and probably use OAUTH 2 authentication.  The connection string will contain the IP address (or host name) on the network.

Comment: Is a sql database, but the problem is it just accepts vpn connections, so if i put the connection string but i'm not connected to the vpn it won't work.

Comment: You must have an Route to the machine (Using IP, ethernet).  A linux machine can be on same network as windows.  both use ethernet.  I do not know your network so I not sure why you do not have a route.  Is issue a firewall?  To use OAUTH see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?force_isolation=true&view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-device-code-flow-authentication